# Output Array Objects from JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

**JSON**:

```
{
    "path": "src/main/java/tools/generator/data/RecordPart.java",
    "revisions": 1,
    "codeLines": 18,
    "authors": [
      {
        "name": "tester",
        "commits": 1
      }
      {
        "name": "tester2",
        "commits": 6
      }
    ]
  },
...
```

And want to get out this JSON in Javascript:

**My Code:**

```
var jsonSTRING= "[{\"path\": \"src/main/java/tools/generator/data/RecordPart.java\",\"revisions\": 25,\"codeLines\": 18,\"authors\": [{\"name\": \"User1\",\"commits\": 7}]},{\"path\": \"src/main/java/tools/generator/data/RecordTotal.java\", \"revisions\": 55,\"codeLines\": 23,\"authors\": [{\"name\": \"User1\",\"commits\": 5}]},{\"path\": \"src/main/resources/test.xml\",\"revisions\": 102,\"codeLines\": 44,\"authors\": [{\"name\": \"User1\",\"commits\": 7}]}]";  

var json = JSON.parse(jsonSTRING);

for(var i=0;i < json.length ; i++)
{
console.debug( json[i]["path"] );
console.debug( json[i]["revisions"] );
console.debug( json[i]["codeLines"] );
console.debug( json[i]["authors"] );
}
```

The problem is if I get this out the output is :

```
src/main/java/tools/generator/data/RecordPart.java  
25  
18  
[ Object ] [ Object ]
```

How can i output the authors `name` and `commits` ?

Comment: Did you tried to `JSON.stringify` output? How do you want to output it, splitted by commas, etc.?

Comment: @dloeda yes but then i get the brackets in my output

Comment: Also, you could do `json[i]["authors"].join(', ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var jsonSTRING= "[{\"path\": \"src/main/java/tools/generator/data/RecordPart.java\",\"revisions\": 25,\"codeLines\": 18,\"authors\": [{\"name\": \"User1\",\"commits\": 7}]},{\"path\": \"src/main/java/tools/generator/data/RecordTotal.java\", \"revisions\": 55,\"codeLines\": 23,\"authors\": [{\"name\": \"User1\",\"commits\": 5}]},{\"path\": \"src/main/resources/test.xml\",\"revisions\": 102,\"codeLines\": 44,\"authors\": [{\"name\": \"User1\",\"commits\": 7}]}]";  

var json = JSON.parse(jsonSTRING);

for(var i=0;i < json.length ; i++)
{
console.debug( json[i]["path"] );
console.debug( json[i]["revisions"] );
console.debug( json[i]["codeLines"] );
for(var j=0; j<json[i]["authors"].length; j++) {
    console.debug( json[i]["authors"][j].name );
    console.debug( json[i]["authors"][j].commits );
}
console.debug( json[i]["authors"] );
}
```

You should read the array as well.

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
var jsonSTRING= "[{\"path\": \"src/main/java/tools/generator/data/RecordPart.java\",\"revisions\": 25,\"codeLines\": 18,\"authors\": [{\"name\": \"User1\",\"commits\": 7}]},{\"path\": \"src/main/java/tools/generator/data/RecordTotal.java\", \"revisions\": 55,\"codeLines\": 23,\"authors\": [{\"name\": \"User1\",\"commits\": 5}]},{\"path\": \"src/main/resources/test.xml\",\"revisions\": 102,\"codeLines\": 44,\"authors\": [{\"name\": \"User1\",\"commits\": 7}]}]";  

var json = JSON.parse(jsonSTRING);

for(var i=0;i < json.length ; i++)
{
    console.debug( json[i]["path"] );
    console.debug( json[i]["revisions"] );
    console.debug( json[i]["codeLines"] );
    for(var k=0; k<json[i]["authors"].length; k++) {
        console.debug( json[i]["authors"][k].name );
        console.debug( json[i]["authors"][k].commits );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your authors field is an array, you could try the following:

```
let authors = json.authors;


authors.forEach((author)=>{
    console.log(author.name);
    console.log(author.commits);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is read through the authors array too

```
  var jsonSTRING= "[{\"path\": \"src/main/java/tools/generator/data/RecordPart.java\",\"revisions\": 25,\"codeLines\": 18,\"authors\": [{\"name\": \"User1\",\"commits\": 7}]},{\"path\": \"src/main/java/tools/generator/data/RecordTotal.java\", \"revisions\": 55,\"codeLines\": 23,\"authors\": [{\"name\": \"User1\",\"commits\": 5}]},{\"path\": \"src/main/resources/test.xml\",\"revisions\": 102,\"codeLines\": 44,\"authors\": [{\"name\": \"User1\",\"commits\": 7}]}]";  

  var json = JSON.parse(jsonSTRING);

   json.filter(function(i){

       console.debug( i["path"] );
       console.debug( i["revisions"] );
       console.debug( i["codeLines"] );

      i["authors"].filter(function(o){
         console.debug( o["name"] );
         console.debug( o["commits"] );
   })
 });
```

i hope it helps